# Received Intent Breaks The Activity

Tags: java, android

I have an application that receives intent. My manifest file includes the share intent

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

On my onCreate method, I check the intent with method handleIncomingIntent.

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize ButterKnife
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Handle incoming intent
    handleIncomingIntent();
  }

private void handleIncomingIntent() {
    // Get intent
    Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    String appLinkType = appLinkIntent.getType();

    Utilities.DebugMessage("action: " + appLinkAction);
    Utilities.DebugMessage("type: " + appLinkType);

    if ( Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(appLinkAction) && (appLinkType != null) ) {
      if ("text/plain".equals(appLinkType)) {
        String url = appLinkIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

        Utilities.DebugMessage("url: " + url);
      }
      else {
        Utilities.onSnackMessage(mViewWindow, "Link is not valid!");
      }
    }
  }
```

On my onStart method, I hide the UI and show the progress bar only.

```
@Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // --> THE ERROR FUNCTION <--
    // Show progress bar and hide everything else
    showUiElements(true, true);
  }

  // Firebase Adapter Listener onDataChanged event
  @Override
  public void onDataChanged() {
    Utilities.DebugMessage("onDataChanged called!");
    // Show/hide content if the query returns empty.
    if (mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
      showUiElements(false, true);
    } else {
      showUiElements(false, false);
    }
  }

private void showUiElements(final Boolean isProgress, final Boolean isEmpty){
//    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//      @Override
//      public void run() {
        if (isProgress) {
          Utilities.DebugMessage("progress: true");
          // Show loading progress bar
          mLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          mPlayFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
          Utilities.DebugMessage("progress: false, isEmpty: " + isEmpty.toString());
          mLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          if (isEmpty) {
            mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mPlayFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          } else {
            mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
        }
//      }
//    });
  }
```

The app works without problem on normal conditions (which means an intent is not received). onStart works good, first it shows the progress bar and then shows the recycler view.

However, when I share an intent to my app,

- onCreate method is called again (I'm not sure why it's called even
  if the app is not closed)
- handleIncomingIntent finds the url
  without problem.
- onStart method is called -> progress bar is shown,
  everything else is hidden

After this step, error goes as

- onDataChanged is called -> which should hide the progress bar.

I can even see it on the logs

```
onDataChanged called!
progress: false, isEmpty: false
```

But it doesn't hide the progress bar, nor shows other elements.

What am I doing wrong here?

The interesting thing here is, when the intent is received, the progress bar is not hidden, when I press back key, it goes back to the main activity again, still progress bar is shown. (it should quit the app though)

Thank you for your help,

Happy new years,

The logcat output:

```
01-03 11:25:46.512 27162-27162/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-03 11:25:46.513 27162-27162/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
01-03 11:25:46.527 27162-27169/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
01-03 11:25:46.527 27162-27169/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
01-03 11:25:46.843 27162-27162/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.deneme.deneme-1/lib/x86
01-03 11:25:46.897 27162-27162/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
01-03 11:25:46.898 27162-27162/? D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/system/fake-libs:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xb4a10090
01-03 11:25:46.903 27162-27162/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
01-03 11:25:46.904 27162-27162/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
01-03 11:25:46.917 27162-27162/? I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
01-03 11:25:46.924 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 3qBBjVZGupOUSTTntwbkvQ10g8m1 ).
01-03 11:25:46.932 27162-27177/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
01-03 11:25:46.934 27162-27177/? I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
01-03 11:25:46.934 27162-27177/? I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
01-03 11:25:46.935 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
01-03 11:25:46.984 27162-27162/? V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -1808100766
01-03 11:25:46.989 27162-27162/? V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
01-03 11:25:46.990 27162-27162/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
01-03 11:25:46.991 27162-27162/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-03 11:25:47.001 27162-27184/? V/FA: Collection enabled
01-03 11:25:47.001 27162-27184/? V/FA: App package, google app id: com.deneme.deneme, 1:752598847908:android:7b6abca737394e84
01-03 11:25:47.001 27162-27184/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
01-03 11:25:47.001 27162-27184/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
01-03 11:25:47.001 27162-27184/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.deneme.deneme
01-03 11:25:47.001 27162-27184/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
01-03 11:25:47.011 27162-27184/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-03 11:25:47.016 27162-27184/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-03 11:25:47.061 27162-27162/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-03 11:25:47.064 27162-27162/? V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-03 11:25:47.155 27162-27162/? I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration
01-03 11:25:47.304 27162-27179/? W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
01-03 11:25:47.305 27162-27162/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
01-03 11:25:47.306 27162-27162/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
01-03 11:25:47.391 27162-27162/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
01-03 11:25:47.391 27162-27162/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
01-03 11:25:47.393 27162-27162/? W/linker: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_extracted_libs/x86/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x91
01-03 11:25:47.393 27162-27162/? V/NativeCrypto: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 276 native methods...
01-03 11:25:47.402 27162-27162/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-03 11:25:47.402 27162-27162/? I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
01-03 11:25:47.413 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: action: android.intent.action.MAIN
01-03 11:25:47.413 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: type: null
01-03 11:25:47.414 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: progress: true
01-03 11:25:47.440 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: received url: null
01-03 11:25:47.441 27162-27184/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-03 11:25:47.442 27162-27184/? V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 10299144
01-03 11:25:47.446 27162-27184/? I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
01-03 11:25:47.447 27162-27184/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3997795833285470712}]

                                       [ 01-03 11:25:47.467 27162:27162 D/         ]
                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa9ab4080, tid 27162
01-03 11:25:47.474 27162-27184/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-03 11:25:47.478 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
01-03 11:25:47.478 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
01-03 11:25:47.548 27162-27190/com.deneme.deneme I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-03 11:25:47.548 27162-27190/com.deneme.deneme D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-03 11:25:47.548 27162-27190/com.deneme.deneme W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
01-03 11:25:47.548 27162-27190/com.deneme.deneme D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
01-03 11:25:47.550 27162-27189/com.deneme.deneme I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Start MutationQueue
01-03 11:25:47.565 27162-27189/com.deneme.deneme I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Locally write mutations
01-03 11:25:47.594 27162-27190/com.deneme.deneme D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb48056c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
01-03 11:25:47.622 27162-27190/com.deneme.deneme D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb48056c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4803910)
01-03 11:25:47.666 27162-27162/com.deneme.deneme W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
01-03 11:25:47.678 27162-27190/com.deneme.deneme D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb48056c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4803910)
01-03 11:25:47.712 27162-27189/com.deneme.deneme I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfbk@a0b60c0c
01-03 11:25:47.715 27162-27189/com.deneme.deneme I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfad@b0c110c7
01-03 11:25:47.716 27162-27189/com.deneme.deneme I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfad@f1a9771b
01-03 11:25:47.741 27162-27184/com.deneme.deneme D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-03 11:25:47.741 27162-27184/com.deneme.deneme V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
01-03 11:25:47.846 27162-27162/com.deneme.deneme W/boostdebug: onDataChanged called!
01-03 11:25:47.846 27162-27162/com.deneme.deneme W/boostdebug: progress: false, isEmpty: false
01-03 11:25:47.896 27162-27162/com.deneme.deneme W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
01-03 11:25:47.903 27162-27167/com.deneme.deneme I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=13KB, data=25KB
01-03 11:25:47.903 27162-27167/com.deneme.deneme I/art: After code cache collection, code=6KB, data=22KB
01-03 11:25:47.903 27162-27167/com.deneme.deneme I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
01-03 11:25:48.090 27162-27162/com.deneme.deneme I/ViewTarget: Glide treats LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT as a request for an image the size of this device's screen dimensions. If you want to load the original image and are ok with the corresponding memory cost and OOMs (depending on the input size), use .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL). Otherwise, use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, set layout_width and layout_height to fixed dimension, or use .override() with fixed dimensions.
01-03 11:25:48.130 27162-27189/com.deneme.deneme W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
01-03 11:25:48.131 27162-27189/com.deneme.deneme W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
01-03 11:25:48.205 27162-27167/com.deneme.deneme I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=51KB, data=62KB
01-03 11:25:48.205 27162-27167/com.deneme.deneme I/art: After code cache collection, code=51KB, data=62KB
01-03 11:25:48.205 27162-27167/com.deneme.deneme I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
01-03 11:25:48.543 27162-27169/com.deneme.deneme I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-03 11:25:50.245 27162-27175/? D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 3qBBjVZGupOUSTTntwbkvQ10g8m1 ).
01-03 11:25:50.246 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
01-03 11:25:50.246 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
01-03 11:25:50.686 27162-27174/? D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 3qBBjVZGupOUSTTntwbkvQ10g8m1 ).
01-03 11:25:50.686 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
01-03 11:25:50.686 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
01-03 11:25:50.687 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Successfully fetched token.
01-03 11:25:50.703 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream is ready
01-03 11:25:51.062 27162-27175/? D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 3qBBjVZGupOUSTTntwbkvQ10g8m1 ).
01-03 11:25:51.063 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
01-03 11:25:51.063 27162-27162/? D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
01-03 11:25:51.064 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Successfully fetched token.
01-03 11:25:51.066 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream is ready
01-03 11:25:51.674 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream received headers: {date=Wed, 03 Jan 2018 08:26:00 GMT}
01-03 11:25:51.676 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfbm@cac5c280
01-03 11:25:51.677 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Set stream token
01-03 11:25:51.680 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfbk@a5d3816e
01-03 11:25:51.800 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received headers: {date=Wed, 03 Jan 2018 08:26:00 GMT}
01-03 11:25:51.802 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@a491c0c1
01-03 11:25:51.803 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@aeb3c951
01-03 11:25:51.804 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@72b77077
01-03 11:25:51.906 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@74516935
01-03 11:25:51.908 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@65b025c0
01-03 11:25:51.921 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@1aa8a89
01-03 11:25:51.922 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@a62bb97f
01-03 11:25:52.017 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfbm@d7d0a613
01-03 11:25:52.018 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Acknowledge batch
01-03 11:25:52.032 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@7b4bda9
01-03 11:25:52.033 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@fe248a45
01-03 11:25:52.033 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@e07f85a5
01-03 11:25:52.036 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
01-03 11:25:52.780 27162-27184/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
01-03 11:25:55.864 27162-27184/? V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 8424
01-03 11:25:55.864 27162-27184/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-03 11:25:55.865 27162-27184/? V/FA: Activity paused, time: 10307568
01-03 11:25:55.867 27162-27184/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=8424, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3997795833285470712}]
01-03 11:25:55.874 27162-27184/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-03 11:25:56.002 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: onSaveInstanceState: Bundle[{}]
01-03 11:25:56.006 27162-27184/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-03 11:25:56.006 27162-27184/? V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
01-03 11:25:56.008 27162-27190/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb48056c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4803910)
01-03 11:25:56.011 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Release query
01-03 11:25:56.017 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfad@26749b68
01-03 11:25:56.018 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Release query
01-03 11:25:56.022 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfad@26749bd2
01-03 11:25:56.210 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@9bd0c020
01-03 11:25:56.257 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@cdab106a
01-03 11:25:59.811 27162-27162/? V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-03 11:25:59.832 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: action: android.intent.action.SEND
01-03 11:25:59.832 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: type: text/plain
01-03 11:25:59.832 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: url: https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=deneme&oq=deneme&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j5j0.659j0j4&client=ms-unknown&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8
01-03 11:25:59.844 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: progress: true
01-03 11:25:59.846 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: received url: null
01-03 11:25:59.846 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Locally write mutations
01-03 11:25:59.848 27162-27184/? V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 10311551
01-03 11:25:59.851 27162-27184/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-3997795833285470712, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3997795833285470711}]
01-03 11:25:59.861 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfbk@94933d33
01-03 11:25:59.875 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfad@24e8d524
01-03 11:25:59.889 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfad@3aa7a000
01-03 11:25:59.987 27162-27167/? I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=118KB, data=126KB
01-03 11:25:59.987 27162-27167/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
01-03 11:25:59.987 27162-27167/? I/art: After code cache collection, code=96KB, data=74KB
01-03 11:26:00.010 27162-27190/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb48056c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4803910)
01-03 11:26:00.077 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: onDataChanged called!
01-03 11:26:00.077 27162-27162/? W/boostdebug: progress: false, isEmpty: false
01-03 11:26:00.275 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@72b77077
01-03 11:26:00.278 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@e07f85a5
01-03 11:26:00.278 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
01-03 11:26:00.284 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@a491c0c1
01-03 11:26:00.285 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfbm@e364b24e
01-03 11:26:00.285 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Acknowledge batch
01-03 11:26:01.300 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@e0585c51
01-03 11:26:01.301 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@717a1d60
01-03 11:26:01.301 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@a3546daa
01-03 11:26:01.302 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@d88929c5
01-03 11:26:01.302 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
01-03 11:26:01.311 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@4cb3ca3d
01-03 11:26:01.311 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
01-03 11:26:01.425 27162-27184/? V/FA: Session started, time: 10313130
01-03 11:26:01.427 27162-27184/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3997795833285470711}]
01-03 11:26:06.452 27162-27184/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
01-03 11:27:00.290 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfbk@23964a0b
01-03 11:27:00.290 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeur]: (66a0266) Closing stream client-side
01-03 11:27:01.408 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeup]: (8c249a7) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfaf@26324318
01-03 11:27:01.408 27162-27189/? I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzepu]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
```

Comment: Include logcat output to help undrestand the question

Comment: the logcat output is added.

Comment: The interesting thing on the logcat is, it's seen ? instead of my app name right after I share intent.
01-03 11:25:47.548 27162-27190/com.deneme.deneme 
01-03 11:25:56.006 27162-27184/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another instance of your activity is likely being created.  You need to change the [launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) attribute for your activity to something like singleTop, and use `onNewIntent()` to handle additional actions.

Comment: launchMode worked like a charm. I didn't know the activity was restarted on new intent. Learned new thing today. Thank you,